# black screen appears after facebook authenticates , facebook dialog not shown

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i am integrating login through facebook in an ios app , in which during the app launch i show an alert to the user , and when the user clicks on the OK button on the alert view , then the FB login dialog is shown to the user .The problem is when i click on the home button and relaunch the app to show the alert, then after clicking on OK does not show the user the facebook login dialog. i have used the facebook ios sdk 3.0 and xcode 4.5 gm. *Interestingly when i kill the app from background every thing works fine.*below is the code in the app did finish launching for facebook

```
if (!self.session.isOpen)
{
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes",
                            @"read_stream",@"publish_stream",@"email",
                            nil];

    self.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];


    if (self.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)

    {
        // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
        [self.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
    }];
    }
}
```

this is the method i call when user clicks on the OK button on the alert view

```
-(IBAction) facebookLogin
{

if (self.session.isOpen)
{
    [self.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];        
} 
else
{
    if (self.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        self.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }


    [self.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                              FBSessionState status,
                                              NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"dex is %@",error.description);
        }
    }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this doc on Facebook [developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/).

It explains how to handle login and logout functionalities. Implement as it says, works perfectly. And also you can use the latest 3.1 sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but anyway.
I had same behaviour when I didn't updated my AppDelegate. In swift it should look like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

     FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Some code was here

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```